# How do I count every time a member sends a message? Discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I want to store the amount of messages each user has sent in a json file. So everytime a user sends a message +1 to their amount in a json file. Then they can use a command to see how many messages they have sent. Im unsure how to do this as I am very unfamiliar with writing and reading to files.

Comment: Hey there Fu510N, welcome to Stack. Next time, please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as Stackoverflow is not supposed to be a code giving website. Do also visit [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can help you better in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you would want to have an [on message event.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message)
Then, just open your json file, and add 1 to it. I would format it like so: `{userid: messages}`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the inbuilt json module -

```py
import json
Messages=json.load(open('messages.json'))
```

And when you want to edit -

```py
Messages[username]+=1
json.dump(Messages,open('messages.json','w'))
```

Comment: remember to close `open` handles

Comment: What exactly am I supposed to put in place of username? I tried message. author.id but then it gives me an error.

Comment: what is the error?